# GitLab-CI Multi Runner can't fetch gitlab repo and returns http error

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using Gitlab-CI-Multi-Runner on Windows (64 bit), and have configured it to run with the default shell. The connectivity with the Gitlab server is fine, but when it tries to run a build, it is cloning the repository using HTTP endpoint. My repo is quite big, and the Gitlab NGINX fails with an error. SSH endpoint works perfectly.

How do I make my GitLab-CI-Multi-Runner use the SSH endpoint when cloning the repo for executing a build?

Note: The same problem existed with the older Gitlab-CI-Runner for Windows which was written using C#.

Comment: Up. I am facing the very same problem. Did you happen to find a solution?

Comment: Nopes. Did not find a solution, yet.

Comment: found a solution. posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the timeout of the unicorn engine workers, that is too short to allow big repositories to be cloned/pushed.

in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` uncomment and set

```
unicorn['worker_timeout'] = 1200
```

(hopefully enough).

then issue

```
# gitlab-ctl reconfigure
# gitlab-ctl restart
```

that works for me.

Comment: a more robust solution would be to get SSH download working.

Comment: @Nishith, I agree..however this is for the moment the solution suggested in the gitlab-ci-runner forum. Somehow it makes general sense, as if you try to clone/push your (big) repo via http, then it won't work either for the same timeout problem.